# Unable to print menu links using menu_navigation_links

Tags: theming, routes

I'm using a custom template and attempting to customize the output of specific menu items. However when I attempt to output each link in the menu specified it outputs nothing. menu-it is the machine name of the menu.

```
<?php $menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-it', 1);
    foreach($menu as $item){
        print $item;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to print that menu would be:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => $menu), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'site-menu')) ));?>
```

or similar.

If you want to do something different for individual items then in template.php you could implement:

```
function THEME_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
    // if certain menu item, do something different
}
```